# SFDX Error "running force:package:create: Invalid character in header content ["projectdir"]"

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm having an error when running a sfdx command :

> "ERROR running force:package:create:  Invalid character in header
>   content ["projectdir"]".

The command is : `sfdx force:package:create --name dreamhouse --description "My DreamHouse Package" --packagetype Unlocked --path force-app --nonamespace --targetdevhubusername MyTP2`

What does it mean "Invalid character in header content ["projectdir"]"?

I'm doing this trailhead module : Build Your First Unlocked Package.

Comment: Are you working in  folder that has unusual characters in its full path?

Comment: can you post your project full path? as @KeithC said unusual characters exist in project path